# How do mains LED strips work?

Tags: mains, led-strip, dimming

I want to build an efficient dimmable LED strip lighting that's why not much current should be carried on the copper traces of the strip. Also not all LED current must be limited with resistors. Thus, I chose to go with 220V LED strip. First thing I want to know is: Are 220V LEDs worth the extra struggle in terms of efficiency and brightness if I am using 5 meters strip only? Because I need dimming and it is very easy to dim 12V strips with a current controlled buck regulator.

There will be 3 modes of brightness (Full, potentiometer 1, potentiometer 2) which are selected by an Arduino either through a relay or an analog switch.

Generally these strips are not connected directly to mains. They are usually cuttable once every meter or half meter. There is a regulator but I don't know what it exactly does.

[image: Mains LED]

**I have few possible plans:**

1. I can cut off the LED strip regulator. For dimming operation, I may use voltage and current controlled buck regulator such as [TPS92640](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps92641.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1711647475900&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Ftps92641) and for the full brightness operation I can turn off current limit and only operate with voltage limit. Sounds complicated already.
2. I can design an AC chopper as simple as that:

[image: AC chopper schematic]

I can switch between potentiometers with a relay and I can short the chopper with another relay for full brightness. But before that I need to know how the onboard regulator works because the AC chopper will be in series with that regulator.

3. There are dimmable mains LED strips. How do these work:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Fixed. Thanks..

Comment: First of all, I presume 100Hz will flicker that's why AC-DC conversion seems nice I agree. I can actually buy a readily made AC-DC converter that outputs a voltage which corresponds to maximum brightness. Then all I need to do is to control the current without worrying about voltage, a current controlled buck converter. The problem is, the voltage I required is around 100VDC and I don't think they make converters with that much Vo.